# How to abbreviate "Check that assumption is not violated for the solution that we got through the assumption"

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

**Note that this is not a math question, but a language one. Nonetheless it requires some understanding of math and I thus hope it is appropriate to be asked here. Also be warned of non rigorous mathematics**

Assume we want to calculate the deflection of a beam, which requires solving

$$
-T_0\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\rho g\sqrt{1+(\frac{du}{dx})^2}=0.
$$
To make life easier we assume that $\frac{du}{dx}\ll 1$ which yields a linear equation which is trivial to solve. How can one more elegantly phrase

> In order to check that the assumptions that were made are at least
>   not too obviously violated, we compute $\dots$ and find $\frac{du}{dx}\ll1$ (where $u$ is the solution of the linear equation).

I can't just say "in order to check that our assumptions are indeed satisfied" because that can plainly not be concluded from looking at the solution of the linear equation. Notwithstanding this logical gap, no one will take you seriously if you do not have such an "assumption check". Another alternative phrasing would be

> We calculate $\frac{du}{dx}\dots \ll 1$, which does not contradict our assumption.

but I find this little informative, especially if it comes after multiple pages of computations.

Comment: How do authors deal with similar questions in textbooks or journals in your discipline? Look for some examples to model your explanation on.

Comment: "Check whether the result we obtained is consistent with the assumptions made in order to derive it"?

Comment: Similar to Clement C: "we find that $\frac{du}{dx}\ll 1$, consistent with our assumption."